# Shared XCTest unit tests for different implementations of interface

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctest

I have two or more implementations of some interface (protocol):

```
protocol Interface {
    func methodOne()
    func methodTwo()
}
```

I want to test each implementation and I don't want to duplicate code. I have couple of options, but none of them satisfies me.

First one is to create test case for `ImplementationA` and subclass it to get test case for `ImplementationB`:

```
class ImplementationATests: XCTestCase {

    var implToTest: Interface!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        implToTest = ImplementationA()
    }

    func testMethodOne() {
        ...
    }

    func testMethodTwo() {
        ...
    }
}


class ImplementationBTests: ImplementationATests {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        implToTest = ImplementationB()
    }
}
```

One of the drawbacks of this method is that I can't have tests which apply only for `ImplementationA`. (e.g. to test some helper method specific to that implementation)

Second option I came up with is creating shared subclass for test cases:

```
class InterfaceTests: XCTestCase {

    var implToTest: Interface!

    func testMethodOne() {
        ...
    }

    func testMethodTwo() {
        ...
    }
}
```

But here those tests will be also executed, and they will fail, because no implementation is assigned to `implToTest`. Of course I can assign some implementation to it, but then I will end with two test cases for the same implementation. The best option would be to somehow disable `InterfaceTests` test case and run only its subclasses. Is it possible?

Third idea I got may seem tricky, but it would satisfy all my needs. Unfortunately it doesn't work.
I decided to create `InterfaceTestable` protocol:

```
protocol InterfaceTestable {
    var implToTest: Interface! { get set }
}
```

and make extension to it with all shared tests:

```
extension InterfaceTestable {

    func testMethodOne() {
        ...
    }

    func testMethodTwo() {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then create test cases for each implementation:

```
class ImplementationATests: XCTestCase, InterfaceTestable {

    var implToTest: Interface!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        implToTest = ImplementationA()
    }

    // some tests which only apply to ImplementationA
}


class ImplementationBTests: XCTestCase, InterfaceTestable {

    var implToTest: Interface!       

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        implToTest = ImplementationB()
    }

    // some tests which only apply to ImplementationB
}
```

Those test cases compile but Xcode doesn't see tests declared in `InterfaceTestable` extension.

Is there any other way to have shared tests for different implementations?

Comment: Very useful question. Suggestion: edit the question down to only a minimal problem statement in the Question. Add "Answers" for each of your 3 approaches. Then people can upvote and discuss each.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I came across the same problem and solved it using your second option.
However, I found a way to prevent the test cases from the base class from running:

Override the `defaultTestSuite()` class method in your base class to return an empty `XCTestSuite`:

```
class InterfaceTests: XCTestCase {

  var implToTest: Interface!

  override class func defaultTestSuite() -> XCTestSuite {
    return XCTestSuite(name: "InterfaceTests Excluded")
  }
}
```

With this no tests from `InterfaceTests` are run. Unfortunately also no tests of `ImplementationATests` either. By overriding `defaultTestSuite()` in `ImplementationATests` this can be solved:

```
class ImplementationATests : XCTestCase {

  override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    implToTest = ImplementationA()
  }

  override class func defaultTestSuite() -> XCTestSuite {
    return XCTestSuite(forTestCaseClass: ImplementationATests.self)
  } 
}
```

Now the test suite of `ImplementationATests` will run all test from `InterfaceTests`, but no tests from `InterfaceTests` are run directly, without setting `implToTest`.

Comment: Looks good. One correction I'm seeing: `override class var defaultTestSuite: XCTestSuite`. (See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496289-defaulttestsuite).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work server-side due to current partial implementation of XCTest's there. :(. See https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest

Comment: And see https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12232 for issues with inherited tests.

Comment: One thing to add: you can remove the need for each subclass to re-implement the "real" `defaultTestSuite`, by instead checking the type of `self`. `(self == InterfaceTests.self) ? XCTestSuite(name: "InterfaceTests Excluded") : super.defaultTestSuite()`. When subclasses inherit this, they'll fail the predicate and hit the `super` case.

Answer (score 2):

The way I've done this before is with a shared base class. Make `implToTest` nillable. In the base class, if an implementation is not provided, simply `return` out of the test in a guard clause.

It's a little annoying that the test run includes reports of the base class tests when it's not doing anything. But that's a small annoyance. The test subclasses will provide useful feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of ithron's solution, if you carefully craft your `defaultTestSuite`, you can remove the need for each subclass to re-override it.

```swift
class InterfaceTests: XCTestCase {
    override class var defaultTestSuite: XCTestSuite {
        // When subclasses inherit this property, they'll fail this check, and hit the `else`.
        // At which point, they'll inherit the full test suite that generated for them.
        if self == AbstractTest.self {
            return XCTestSuite(name: "Empty suite for AbstractSpec")
        } else {
            return super.defaultTestSuite
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the same limitation applies: this won't hide the empty test suite from the Xcode test navigator.

## Generalizing this into a `AbstractTestCase` class

I would go a step further an make a base `class AbstractTestCase: XCTestCase` to store this `defaultTestSuite` trick, from which all your other abstract classes can inherit.

For completeness, to make it truly abstract you'd also want to override all the `XCTestCase` initializers to make them error out if an attempt is made to instantiate your abstract classes. On Apple's platforms, there's 3 initializers to override:

1. `-[XCTestCase init]`
2. `-[XCTestCase initWithSelector:]`
3. `-[XCTestCase initWithInvocation:]`

Unfortunately, this can't be done from Swift because of that last initializer, which uses `NSInvocation`. `NSInvocation` isn't available with Swift (it isn't compatible with Swift's ARC). So you need to implement this in Objective C. Here's my stab at it:

### `AbstractTestCase.h`

```objectivec
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

@interface AbstractTestCase : XCTestCase

@end
```

### `AbstractTestCase.m`

```objectivec
#import "AbstractTestCase.h"

@implementation AbstractTestCase

+ (XCTestSuite *)defaultTestSuite {
    if (self == [AbstractTestCase class]) {
        return [[XCTestSuite alloc] initWithName: @"Empty suite for AbstractTestCase"];
    } else {
        return [super defaultTestSuite];
    }
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    NSAssert(![self isMemberOfClass:[AbstractTestCase class]], @"Do not instantiate this abstract class!");
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithSelector:(SEL)selector {
    self = [super initWithSelector:selector];
    NSAssert(![self isMemberOfClass:[AbstractTestCase class]], @"Do not instantiate this abstract class!");
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation {
    self = [super initWithInvocation:invocation];
    NSAssert(![self isMemberOfClass:[AbstractTestCase class]], @"Do not instantiate this abstract class!");
    return self;
}

@end
```

### Usage

You can then just use this as the superclass of your abstract test, e.g.

```swift
class InterfaceTests: AbstractTestCase {
  var implToTest: Interface!

  func testSharedTest() {

  }
}
```